# Estimation of a two-sided Chernoff bound

Tags: probability

I have come across [this paper](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/varun.kanade/docs/recombination-K11.pdf) which uses the following version of the Chernoff bound (page 7):

> If $X_{i}$ are i.i.d. with mean $\mu$, such that $X_{i}\in[0,1]$,
>   then
>
> $Pr\Bigg[\lnot\Bigg(\frac{\mu}{1+\delta}\leq\frac{1}{m}{\sum^m_{i=1}}X_{i}\leq
> \mu(1+\delta)\Bigg)\Bigg]\leq
> 2e^{-\delta^{2}\mu m/12}$

Which is a two-sided multiplicative Chernoff bound. However it is not an ordinary two-sided bound in the sense that the left bound is not of the form $(1-\delta)\mu$ but $\frac{\mu}{1+\delta}$.

My question is: how did the author of this paper reach this version? Other bounds I've found are looser. Specifically in other textbooks instead of the number 12 in $2e^{-\delta^{2}\mu m/12}$ there are smaller numbers (which makes the bound looser).

The tightest bound I've found is for the one-sided Chernoff bound in the book [Randomized Algorithms by Motwani and Raghavan](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0521474655) (page 72):

> $Pr[X>(1+\delta)\mu]<e^{−\delta^2\mu/4},0<\delta<2e−1$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this bound using [Hoeffding inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) (as it is mentioned in the paper) with some extra condition on the relation of $\mu$ and $\delta$. First see that:
$$
Pr\Bigg[\frac{1}{m}{\sum^m_{i=1}}X_{i}\geq
\mu(1+\delta)\Bigg]\leq \exp(-{2m\mu^2\delta^2})
$$
And for the other side we have:
$$
Pr\Bigg[\frac{\mu}{1+\delta}\geq\frac{1}{m}{\sum^m_{i=1}}X_{i}\Bigg]\leq
\exp(-\frac{2m\mu^2\delta^2}{(1+\delta)^2})
$$
Applying union bound we get:
$$
Pr\Bigg[\lnot\Bigg(\frac{\mu}{1+\delta}\leq\frac{1}{m}{\sum^m_{i=1}}X_{i}\leq
\mu(1+\delta)\Bigg)\Bigg]\leq \exp(-{2m\mu^2\delta^2})+\exp(-\frac{2m\mu^2\delta^2}{(1+\delta)^2}).
$$
Note that we  can show:
$$
\frac{2m\mu^2\delta^2}{(1+\delta)^2}<2m\mu^2\delta^2 
$$
and using that on:
$$
Pr\Bigg[\lnot\Bigg(\frac{\mu}{1+\delta}\leq\frac{1}{m}{\sum^m_{i=1}}X_{i}\leq
\mu(1+\delta)\Bigg)\Bigg]\leq 2\exp(-\frac{2m\mu^2\delta^2}{(1+\delta)^2}).
$$
The desired inequality follows if we prove the following
$$
\frac{2m\mu^2\delta^2}{(1+\delta)^2}>
\frac{\delta^{2}\mu m}{12}.
$$
But this is equivalent to:
$$
\frac{2\mu}{(1+\delta)^2}>
\frac{1}{12}\implies (1+\delta)^2<24\mu.
$$
Therefore under this extra condition $(1+\delta)^2<24\mu$, the desired inequality follows.

Comment: Thanks! A few clarifications though: 

1. In the first side, isn't it the case that:
$$
Pr\Bigg[\frac{1}{m}{\sum^m_{i=1}}X_{i}\geq
\mu(1+\delta)\Bigg]\leq \exp(-{2m\mu^2\delta^2})
$$

2. I didn't quite understand how having that constraint helps to reach the inequality. Can you clarify? 
In addition, since $\mu\leq 1$, isn't it the case also that $(1+\delta)^2<24$? I ask since the author of the paper didn't specify such a relation between \delta and \mu, and maybe it can be avoided.

Comment: @user3456547, 1. You are right about this; I corrected it in the answer. 2. Of course what I show is only a sufficient condition; I do not know if the condition can be avoided.